# How can I use `packed_float3` in a bridging header between Swift and Metal?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I need to pass a struct with a `packed_float3` (`MTLPackedFloat3`) value from Swift into my Metal shader. I am currently sharing types between Swift and metal using a bridging header. Here's the struct I am trying to write:

```c
typedef struct {
    packed_float3 value;
} CustomData;
```

However when I try using `packed_float3`, I get the following error:

```
unknown type name 'packed_float3'
```

I've tried all sort of type variations including `MTLPackedFloat3`, `packed_simd_float3`, `metal::packed_float3`, `vector_packed_float3`, `packed<float, 3>` but none of them work. I've also tried including various other headers such as `<metal/metal.h>` or `<metal/MTLAccelerationStructureTypes.h>` but this often produces other compiler errors

How can I use packed values in bridging headers without having to define my own types?

Comment: Related discussion on the Swift forum: https://forums.swift.org/t/no-simd-packed-float3-in-swift/61227

Answer (score 0):

There's likely a better way to do this but here's what worked for me:

I believe the root cause is that the bridging header is essentially "built" twice in two different environments: once for Swift and once for Metal. `packed_float3` for example is always defined in Metal but isn't defined in Swift. On the other hand, `MTLPackedFloat3` works fine in Swift isn't defined in Metal.

As a workaround, we can use preprocessing to vary the types used in the Metal compile vs in the swift compile. A simple way to do this is to check if `__METAL_VERSION__` is defined as it will only be defined when the header is included in Metal. Now for Swift, we can alias `packed_float3` to the Swift type `MTLPackedFloat3`:

```c
#ifndef __METAL_VERSION__
#include <metal/metal.h>
typedef MTLPackedFloat3 packed_float3;
#endif
```

This code will only be active in the Swift compile. It also counts on `MTLPackedFloat3` and `packed_float3` having the same data layout. Now you can use `packed_float3` in the header for both Swift and Metal!

Interested to hear if there's a better approach because this is pretty ugly

Comment: I mean, you can just straight up define the `packed_float3` the same way it's defined in metal `typedef __attribute__((__packed_vector_type__(3))) float packed_float3;`

Comment: That warns `unknown attribute '__packed_vector_type__' ignored` and errors if you try using `MTLPackedFloat3` with it: `Cannot convert value of type 'MTLPackedFloat3' (aka '_MTLPackedFloat3') to expected argument type 'packed_float3' (aka 'Float')`

Comment: Indeed, I checked, for myself I defined `typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) packed_float3
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} packed_float3;`

Comment: The caveat is that they are layout compatible, but obviously from standpoint of the compiler they are different types.